# MoviePy: обрезать видео

Tags: python

Нужно обрезать первые 15 секунд видео. `cutout` не работает почему-то:

```
files = os.listdir('video/')
video = []
for a in files:
    print(a)
    if a.endswith(".mp4"):
        video.append(a)
if len(video) == 0:
    print('Ошибка\n')
else:
    for a in video:
        video = VideoFileClip('video/'+a).cutout(00.00,00.15) 
        print(str(video.duration))
        result = fadein(result,12)
        result = mirror_x(result,  apply_to = 'mask') 
        result.write_videofile("new_video/new_"+a,fps=30)
```

Видео на выходе получается той же продолжительности.
Может быть, есть ещё способы, или я использую этот неправильно?

Comment: Скинь код полностью, возможно неверно сохраняешь видео. И, кстати, обрезаешь не 15 секунд, а 15 миллисекунд.
И вроде бы так будет правильнее (не уверен):
```cutout(00:00:15.00)```

Comment: Обновил сообщение с кодом.

Comment: Как я и говорил, ты сохраняешь не обрезанное видео, а оригинальное, в данном случае будет правильно: ```result.write_videofile("new_video/new_"+video,fps=30) ```

Comment: замена "а" на "video" даст только ошибку, в находится str(название видео), попробую еще твой вариант формата длительности для cutout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснилось, что cutout обрезает ту часть видео, которую укажешь, то есть не оставит с 0 до 15, а отрежет 15 секунд начала видео.

```py
files = os.listdir('video/')
video = []
for a in files:
    print(a)
    if a.endswith(".mp4"):
        video.append(a)
if len(video) == 0:
    print('Ошибка\n')
else:
    for a in video:
        # Выясняем длину исходного видео
        video = VideoFileClip('video/'+a)
        #Обрезаем видео с 15 секунд до его конца округляя длину исходного видео 
        video = video.cutout(15,round(video.duration))
        #Сохранение
        video.write_videofile("new_video/new_"+a,fps=30)
```

Comment: Так и есть, мне это и нужно было (убрать первые 15 секунд из видео), в первоначальном варианте который я писал обрезалось 15мс как вы и написали, а я подумал что оно не работает вообще т.к длительность отображалась только мм.сс

Comment: А, ну тогда просто ```cutout(0,15)```

Comment: Единственная проблема что "рендер" занимает слишком много времени, в видеоредакторе рендер проходит быстрее.

Comment: За автоматизацию приходится платить)